# Batch updating posts' tags, Uppercasing them

Tags: ruby, jekyll

I am running a jekyll site with lots of imported posts (approx 900). The tags are a mess and I want to clean that up. Obviously some of that can be scripted, but I cannot see how, in Jekyll.

To begin with, I want to uppercase all tags. Turn "ruby" into "Ruby". And leave "PHP" as "PHP".

1. How do I loop trough all my posts outside of the context of a FrontMatter file? E.g. in IRB, or any other Ruby file.
2. How do I modify and save the parsed posts?

I guess this can be done with some awk and sed magic, but since jekyll already *is* a parser and has intricate knowledge of what a tag, a post and such is, awk-sed-grepping seems awkward and inefficient.

Comment: Is it possible to provide any code as a starting point? Or at least what the "imported post" data looks like?

Comment: I'm going through a similar process, but I'm approaching it a little differently. My goal is to scrub everything with scripts (and manually when necessary) outside of jekyll. That way, I only have to do the work one time and won't have to worry about adding logic/code/potential bugs to jekyll.

Comment: @MarkThomas I will give an update later this week. Right now, I was hoping for a lead as to how to achieve this in Jekyll. I don't have any lead, hence the lack of detail and code in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have your tags in the YAML block at the top of your posts already, I would use this tip from the vimninjas: http://www.vimninjas.com/2012/09/19/replace-multiple/

```
:args _posts/*.md
:argdo :%s/*tag_old*/*tag_new*/ge | update
```